# Exceptions in projects after Tomcat server upgrade

Tags: java, tomcat

We are trying to upgrade our Tomcat version from 7.0.73 to a newer version. On ANY higher version everything runs fine except our "DBPrism Servlet Engine". It deploys without any issues, but when running the test it throws the following exception in the C-Prompt:

```
14-Sep-2017 13:00:36.074 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] 
org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getParser Digester.getParser:
    org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: SAX feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/allow-java-encodings' not recognized.
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.setFeature(NonValidatingParser.java:1696)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.SAXParser.setFeature(SAXParser.java:266)
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory.newSAXParser(JXSAXParserFactory.java:88)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getParser(Digester.java:599)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:771)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1441)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.PersistentProviderRegistrations.loadProviders(PersistentProviderRegistrations.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl.loadPersistentRegistrations(AuthConfigFactoryImpl.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl.<init>(AuthConfigFactoryImpl.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory$1.run(AuthConfigFactory.java:76)
    at javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory$1.run(AuthConfigFactory.java:66)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory.getFactory(AuthConfigFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.findJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1199)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.getJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1192)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1374)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I Have looked at multiple posts from different sites to no avail,
any help would be greatly appreciated

Current setup: Windows 10 with latest JDK - 1.8_144

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111629/what-is-the-cause-of-the-following-tomcat-error

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately the system referred to by the lined post is Centos, and refers to some sort of node problem if I am reading it correctly. Also the referred post in their boils down to them just updating from JDK 1.5 - 1.6, I am using JDK 1.8_144(the latest version available)

Comment: try with a newer version of tomcat: https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi#8.0.46

Comment: As mentioned, any version over 7.0.73 causes this. I have tried with all versions up to and including tomcat 9. The once significant difference that I have been able to find though is that all of the newer versions contains a "tomcat-util-scan.jar" which contains the class causing the exception, this class is NOT part of the 7.0.73 lib.

Comment: my bad I did misread

Comment: I have a similar Error, Windows 10, Java 8-191, Tomcat 9.0.12, I tried removing some older xerces/crimson/sax libraries from my application but still have this problem. Have you found anything on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed here worked for me: [java.lang.SecurityException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature: http://apache.org/xml/features/allow-java-encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944803/java-lang-securityexception-org-xml-sax-saxnotrecognizedexception-feature-htt)

Shutdown the Tomcat server.
Using a text editor open the catalina.properties file. It is usually located in /install-path-to-tomcat/conf/. Make a copy of this file before you continue further.
At the very top of the file add the following properties:

javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl

Unfortunately, I can't make easily config changes to Tomcat, I am still looking on how to fix this from the web application that I 'm trying to deploy.